# OpenGL - sphere shrinking and expanding

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm revising for an OpenGL exam and keep coming across this question on past papers. It's not something I've been taught and I was wondering if anyone could set me off in the right direction.

Sorry I haven't added what I have so far, there's not much because I don't really understand the question either.

"You wish to create a simple animation that shows a small red sphere shrinking and expanding. Specifically the radius oscillates sinusoidally between 0.3 and 0.5 in magnitude.

(i) Discuss the role of the glutIdleFunc in the animation.
(ii) Write the display method that performs the above animation;
assume the radius vector R is of type double and is declared with
global scope."

Comment: What do you think are the right answers? What does your display method look like atm?

Comment: what exactly don't you understand? have you never used GLUT ( because it's just a helper library, not something you absolutely must know to use  OpenGL, and thus a rather stupid question for an OpenGL exam imo ), or is it related to drawing the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

1. The [`glutIdleFunc`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node63.html) documentation could set you off in *a* direction. Notice how it does calculations in the background, so a possible answer could be discussing how the animation behaves by setting or *not* setting (or simply leaving empty) that particular callback, respectively.
2. If you are allowed to use [`glutSolidSphere` or `glutWiredSphere`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node81.html) the display method could be quite simple if you know the basics of OpenGL (assuming you've studied and attended class :). But if you have to use OpenGL 3.3 or 4.0+ you will probably have to think about coming up with an algorithm to first generate the vertices of the sphere (simpler) then the indices of the vertices (little bit trickier). There are numerous examples on the Internet and StackOverflow on how to do that, I do believe.

Good luck on your exam!